# regex notepad++ select a word immediately following ( & preceding ) selection

Tags: regex, notepad++, word-boundary

I need to select just the word that follows a specific selection 
( and one that precedes it - both are separate regexes - not to be combine em )

```
the pattern is 
<variable verbiage>
 <one or more spaces or a newline>
"on"
<one or more spaces or a  newline>
 Word_to_select
<optional variable verbiage>
Examples 
1 ) she looks too pretty I never meant Hillary ya da ya ON delta.airlines next word 
2 )yada ya        
Daddy Daddy
     on
united.airlines  hullah
gulla ; 
 3)yada ya         Daddy Daddy  on
American.airlines some 
ricotta cheese
```

I need to get in all cases 
'Following' regex :

```
delta.airlines
united.airlines 
american.airlines
```

'Preceding' regex :

```
ya
Daddy
Daddy
```

What I tried

```
(\S)\s* on \s*(\S+)
```

the selection includes "on" and goes back further .

Comment: `I need to select` do you mean highlight, or what do you mean by this ? Because regex don't do selection.

Answer (score 2):

Look this demo. you can select group 1 to get "preceding" and 2 to select "following".http://regexr.com/3g7ps

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
\bon\s+\K\S+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cdhrgV/1/).

*Match case* option should be deselected or just prepend the pattern with `(?i)`.

**Details**:

- `\bon` - a whole word `on`
- `\s+` - 1 or more whitespaces
- `\K` - match reset operator
- `\S+`  - 1+ non-whitespace symbols.

[image]